# Cannot create table - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a strange case:
It works:

```
    Create table `testasd`(  
  `asd` int(10) NOT NULL,
  primary key (`asd`)
)
```

but this does not work:

```
    Create table `test1`(  
  `asd` int(10) NOT NULL,
  primary key (`asd`)
)
```

> Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: you don't do anything with foreign key and why "Cannot add foreign key constraint" error is occurred?? you have to make sure your questions scenario is correct or not?

Comment: Both works.....

Comment: so this is exactly what I do, the question is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error returned by the mysql is misleading

To find the specific error run this:

> SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;